# Select all fields from a table where a field in another table with an ID is equal to a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

**Ads**: Fields `ID`, `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
+----+---+-------+------+
| ID | A | B     | C    |
+----+---+-------+------+
|  1 | x | y     | z    |
|  2 | c | v     | b    |
|  3 | n | n     | m    |
+----+---+-------+------+
```

**Requests**: Fields `ID`, `AdID`, and `Status`:

```
+----+------+----------+
| ID | AdID |  Status  |
+----+------+----------+
|  3 |    1 | pending  |
|  4 |    2 | approved |
|  5 |    3 | pending  |
+----+------+----------+
```

`ID` (from `Ads`) = `AdID` (from `Requests`).

Now, I want to get all records from `Ads` where `AdID`'s (from `Requests`) `Status` equals `pending`. `AdId` here would be *the value `ID` from `Ads`*.

So, with the above tables, the result I'd get would be ID 1 and 3 from Ads:

```
+----+---+---+---+
| ID | A | B | C |
+----+---+---+---+
|  1 | x | y | z |
|  3 | n | n | m |
+----+---+---+---+
```

This is the closest I've got so far, but this obviously doesn't work because it can only select one row - whereas I need to select many:

```
SELECT * FROM Ads WHERE ID = (SELECT AdID FROM Requests WHERE Status = 'pending')
```

This might not make sense - please ask if I haven't explained it well - I'll help as much as possible :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IN` in place of `=`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Ads 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT AdID FROM Requests WHERE Status = 'pending')
```

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Yes indeed! This is my lucky post! :=)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Ads A LEFT JOIN Requests R ON A.ID=R.AdID WHERE R.AdID='pending';
```