# Can I use a subquery's result as well?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have 2 tables:

Ads: Fields `ID`, `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
+----+---+-------+------+
| ID | A | B     | C    |
+----+---+-------+------+
|  1 | x | y     | z    |
|  2 | c | v     | b    |
|  3 | n | n     | m    |
+----+---+-------+------+
```

Requests: Fields `ID`, `AdID`, and `Status`:

```
+----+------+----------+
| ID | AdID |  Status  |
+----+------+----------+
|  3 |    1 | approved |
|  4 |    2 | pending  |
|  5 |    3 | rejected |
+----+------+----------+
```

`ID` (from `Ads`) = `AdID` (from `Requests`).

I have the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Ads WHERE ID IN (SELECT AdID FROM Requests WHERE Status = 'approved' OR Status = 'rejected')
```

This gives me the rows with IDs `1` and `3` from `Ads`. Now my question is, can I use the 'approved' or 'rejected' from the subquery as well?

So is there a way I can say:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Ads WHERE ID IN (SELECT AdID FROM Requests WHERE Status = 'approved' OR Status = 'rejected')";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['Status']; //<--- doesn't work right now. Want it to say 'approved'/'rejected'
}
```

and it works?

Comment: (this is a follow up question from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30831325/3541881))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `where ... in` query is basically a filter.  You can do the same with a filtering join:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    Ads a
JOIN    Requests r
ON      a.ID = r.AdID
WHERE   r.Status in ('approved', 'rejected')
```

Unlike a `where ... in` filter, an `inner join` filter includes the columns from the other table in the result.

Answer (score 0):

It should give you an error. You selected only the table Ads, where there is no Status column. At first sight, if you do not need other columns you can just query the table Requests

```
Select /*Distinct*/ /*Adid, */ Status from Requests
 WHERE Status = 'approved' OR Status = 'rejected'
```

If you need also some columns from Ads, make a join

```
 Select a.Id, a.A,R.Status 
 from Ads a inner join Requests r on a.ID=r.AdId
 WHERE Status = 'approved' OR Status = 'rejected'
```